# How to add a custom People Search results count?

Tags: 2013, search-results, people-search

I want to add some statistics like **"Results 1-10 of 572"** in my search people result.

I have a personal Control_SearchResult.html file.

I found the code that I have to modify :

```
 <div class="ms-srch-resultFooter">             
                if(ctx.ClientControl.get_showResultCount() && ctx.DataProvider.get_totalRows() > 0){                        
                    var start = ctx.DataProvider.get_currentQueryState().s;
                    var resultsPerPage = ctx.DataProvider.get_resultsPerPage();
                    var totalRows = ctx.DataProvider.get_totalRows();
                    var countDisplayString = Srch.Res.rs_ApproximateResultCount;
                    var startRows = ctx.DataProvider.get_startRows();
                    if (start + resultsPerPage > totalRows) { countDisplayString = (totalRows == 1)? Srch.Res.rs_SingleResultCount : Srch.Res.rs_ResultCount; }

                    <div id="ResultCount" class="ms-srch-resultscount">
                        _#= String.format($htmlEncode(countDisplayString), $htmlEncode(totalRows.localeFormat("N0"))) =#_
                    </div>

                }
```

But I don't see how to modify this code? How to get startRow, rowLimit...?

Or there is another solution?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found, in the **Control_SearchResults.html** file, you can custom the result count.